# Is Managed Identity feature in preview for Service Fabric Cluster?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, preview

We plan to use Managed Identity feature for Service Fabric Cluster. The documentation does not say if the feature is generally available or in preview. Can someone please confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-best-practices-security#authenticate-service-fabric-applications-to-azure-resources-using-managed-service-identity-msi):

> Azure Service Fabric clusters are hosted on Virtual Machine Scale Sets, whcih support Managed Service Identity.

So just see the available state of the [Azure Virtual Machine Scale Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities#azure-virtual-machine-scale-sets)(different clouds have the different states):

[image]